# How can div be wider than parent td?

Tags: css

I have a div that is wider than its parent td.

How can it be that? The parent has no overflow set so it should really adapt to its content, right?

CSS of parent td:
[image: css of parent td]

CSS of child div:
[image: css of child div]

Parent TD is 722px wide:
[image: parent td is 722 pixels wide]

Child DIV is 960px wide:
[image: child div is 960 pixels wide]

Answer (score 2):

You have a table with a set width of 720px. So the unique Table cell present in it, will have a 720px width too.

Answer (score 0):

Using divs inside table rows can result width difference between child and parent.. I am not sure for your case but giving your child div an inherited width can solve it.

```
#contentslider1{width:inherit}
```

Comment: It needs to have the width, but what is making the table narrow?

Comment: if you can give out jsfiddle, we can help better?